# In App purchase sandbox -- item purchased but error when downloading hosted content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my application with in-app with hosted content, in sandbox mode. I am testing the in-app, all goes well and item is purchased and when it tries to download hosted content it ask for password for test user and after that it gives following error:

```
"Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x16687c80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store} "
```

My application version 1.0 is approved without in-app and after adding in-app items with hosted content it works fine but when I prepare version 2.0 for submission it is not downloading the hosted content and gives cannot connect to iTunes error when downloading hosted content.

Comment: check if your test user is invalid or not

Comment: Sandbox test user works fine, till purchase and when it goes to method -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads, it ask for password for test user and then gives error "Cannot connect to iTunes Connect"

Comment: Same problem here! I tried creating a brand new test user but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Apple servers. The error is posted in Apple developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/253384 and https://devforums.apple.com/message/1071734. It's happening since November 6th. We'll have to wait... :(

Comment: I guess we have to wait till Apple servers issue is fixed.